# ActiveAdmin nested custom resource retrieval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a couple models with a belongs_to relationship. The models both have custom to_param methods set to use a resource key instead of the actual id

```
def to_param
  return self.resource_key
end
```

for my admin models, I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do

  controller do
    def find_resource
      Foo.find_by(resource_key: params[:id])
    end
  end

  panel "Bars" do
  table_for foo.bars do
    column "Title" do |bar|
      link_to bar.title, admin_foo_bar_path(foo, bar)
    end
  end
end

end

ActiveAdmin.register Bar do
  belongs_to :foo

  controller do
    def find_resource
     Bar.find_by(resource_key: params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

Foo works fine, all links are generated with the resource_key in the URL path. The URL is generated correctly for Bar, as well, but when I attempt to open the Bar item I get a message like:
**Couldn't find Foo with id={resource_id}**

I actually don't need the Foo value at all on my Bar view, the Bar resource key is enough data to query on. I either need to tell the app not to try to look up the Foo value, or set Bar to query Foo properly by resource_key instead of id.

I'm using Rails 4 with the 1.0 master branch of AA.

Comment: How are your routes defined? Can you share them in question?

Comment: For AA, I'm just using the default `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible fixes

1) Try to use optional in belongs_to statement

```
 belongs_to :foo, :optional => true #it gives you urls for Bar without Foo
```

2) AA use Inherited_resources gem , try to customize belongs_to (by default it uses find by id)

Example from inherited_resources

```
belongs_to accepts several options to be able to configure the association. For example, if you want urls like "/projects/:project_title/tasks", you can customize how InheritedResources find your projects:

class TasksController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :project, :finder => :find_by_title!, :param => :project_title
end
```

So this should help

```
belongs_to :foo , :finder => :find_by_resource_key!
```