# ActiveAdmin custom resource retrieval - searching by ID when it should be Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Each Person has a Category. I'd like to create a filter where I can select a category and see all the People in that category. Currently when I select a category it's searching for the ID # of the category when it should be searching for the name. Here's the URL 
http://localhost:3000/admin/people?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bcategory_id_in%5D%5B%5D=**1**&commit=Filter&order=id_desc

But it should be http://localhost:3000/admin/people?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bcategory_id_in%5D%5B%5D=**[category name here]**&commit=Filter&order=id_desc

In admin/person.rb

```
filter :category_id, as: :select, collection: proc { Category.all.map }
```

Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495613/activeadmin-nested-custom-resource-retrieval) that I unsuccessfully tried to apply here but doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to filter `Person` objects by `category` attribute, do something like this:

```
filter :category, as: :select, collection: -> { Person.pluck(:category).uniq }
```

`Person.pluck(:category).uniq` will return a list of uniq categories for selection.

---

If `#pluck` wont work, go with: `Person.all.map(&:category).uniq`